# DBC (Design by contract) and AOP(Aspect oriented programming)

Tags: c#, java, programming-languages, aop

I was reading The Pragmatic Programer and by section about DBC ther talk abount how Effel enforces DBC pre and post Condition and Java,C#,C++ dose not.
First thing that came to mind was use AOP (so i googles it DBC and AOP only old links came up)

So what are other programes thoughts abount using AOP to inforce DBC in Java or C#?

Answer (score 3):

While I like the DBC idea, AOP is the wrong weapon for this task in my opinion.

Aspects need special infrastructure complicating your build process

Aspects enforcing contracts need to run in production code, with the risk of actually introducing bugs instead of preventing them.

Aspects do not provide any compile time security, which is really the main aim of DBC.

Don't know about C# but ther doesn't seem to be a mature DBC option available in java land. Therefore I tend to implement contracts as tests. Although not as often as I should

Comment: Actually DBC can be enforced either at run time or at compile time. At compile time it gets really tricky because you may need a full-blown theorem prover, and the assistance of a human mathematician, to prove that contracts are satisfied. So, while I don't use AOP myself, I do think it is a valid approach for runtime DBC enforcement. I'm not sure the additional complexity is worthwhile though.

Answer (score 2):

C# (actually .NET) supports DBC using the [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992) framework and tooling.

It provides an API for declaring your pre-, post- and invariant conditions, plus the ability to perform runtime checks, static checks and generate documentation.

The framework is built-in into .NET framework 4.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Contract4j](http://www.polyglotprogramming.com/contract4j) which uses AspectJ to inforce DBC.

Comment: I am not realy looking for libery more on ideas on Yes can't live with out it or it is not usable. Developer experiences!!